# How do I use Excel VBA to filter 1 criteria across 2 columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns of childrens' names in Column A and Column B. They represent pairs of children who have worked together.

I want to filter for all rows where "Bob" has worked with any other kid.  So I want to filter for all rows for which 1 criteria (Bob) shows up in either Column A OR Column B.

I want to put these rows, or pairs of kids, into an array.  How do I do this?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to create a helper column with an OR formula checking for "Bob" in either column and then filtering that column.  Or you could use my reply to your earlier post and Union the two ranges together.

Comment: I know how to achieve what I want by using the sheet and the helper column with the criteria inside it.  BUT, that's not what I'm trying to do.  I want to avoid using the Excel sheet at all and accomplish the using JUST VBA code.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Doug Glancy...do you have the link to your earlier post regarding Union the 2 ranges together?  I cannot find the post.

Comment: @phan, you accepted an answer that doesn't put the pairs of kids into an array. Is that something you needed to do?

Comment: @head it's the filtering that i care about since excel's filter mode is fast.  like your solution, once i have the results in a sheet, i get how to put it into an array from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen Doug's answer on Union of Ranges. But here is an example. This uses `Autofilter` instead of looping through ranges. I have commented the code so you should not have problem understanding it.

**CODE**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim Lrow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get last row of Col A
        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Identify the range
        Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & Lrow)

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Identify the range in Col A Which has BOB
        With rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Bob"
            Set rngA = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Identify the range in Col B Which has BOB
        With rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Bob"
            Set rngB = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Hide All except the Header row
        rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        '~~> Unhide the rows which have Bob
        Union(rngA, rngB).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It creates a scratch pad sheet, copies any row that has Bob in either column, creates an array from the results, and then deletes the scratchpad.

```
Sub GetBobRows()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim bobCount As Long
    Dim bobRow As Long

    Set src = ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Scratchpad"
    Set tgt = ActiveSheet

    ' assumes two columns with Bob data are A and B and start in row 1
    ' of the activesheet
    lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = src.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    bobCount = 1

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "Bob" Or cell.Offset(, 1).Value = "Bob" Then
            bobRow = cell.Row
            tgt.Range("A" & bobCount & ":B" & bobCount).Value = _
                src.Range("A" & bobRow & ":B" & bobRow).Value
            bobCount = bobCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    Call CreateBobArray(tgt)
    DeleteScratchpad
End Sub

Sub CreateBobArray(tgt As Worksheet)
    Dim vaBobs As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = tgt.Range("A" & tgt.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Read the data from the scratch pad into the bob array
    vaBobs = tgt.Range("A1:B" & lRow).Value
End Sub

Sub DeleteScratchpad()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Scratchpad").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```