# VBA Autofilter Multiple Columns (Union instead of Intersection of Criteria)

Tags: vba, excel

Goal:
I've got SKU's flagged various ways in a wide table. Users will  be selecting what flags they want viewed using checkboxes. I want to filter data that displays **any** of the flags.

I'm familiar with the code

```
With Sheet1
     .AutoFilterMode=False
          With .Range("A1:D200")
               .Autofilter
               .Autofilter Field:=3, Criteria 1:="X"
               .Autofilter Field:=4, Criteria 1:="X"
           End With
End With
```

But this only gives me the intersection of those two conditions. I want the union of those conditions. How can I use the filter to give me the union of the conditions? Is there any easier way to do this?

The only other method I know to use is to loop through the rows individually and checking the criteria, which I know how to do, but seems slow.

(I know that making the data tall instead of wide would be ideal, but the users use the raw data to track aspects and that is not feasible.)

Comment: Can you use a helper column? Essentially the formula in the helper column would say that if any of the flags are checked, then show `Y` else show `N`. Then you just filter on your one column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Excel VBA to filter 1 criteria across 2 columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014529/how-do-i-use-excel-vba-to-filter-1-criteria-across-2-columns).

Comment: That answer will work perfectly MJH! Thank you very much.If you post it as the answer I'll accept it. I wasn't using the proper terms to have  that come up on the search bar.

Comment: Kyle, that would also work. I think MJH's answer is closer to what I was looking for though.